# How can i recover record within 30days even if i deleted something in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I want to link my shared drive's document and sharepoint together. 
Sometime maybe someone will delete the documents carelessly.
How can i retrieve the documents in 30days by sharepoint?
Does it have the function like this?

Comment: You should only tag the version of sharepoint that you are using and should show some attempt to solve the problem, then explain where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you will have a recycle bin that you can view in Site Settings. Items that are deleted from any list or library will appear in the site recycle bin for 30 days.

After this time, items will be moved to the Site Collection Recycle bin for an additional 30 days - if you don't have access to the top level Site Collection - your administrator or IT helpdesk should be able to help.

Comment: Ok. It is helpful to me. Thank you